# Followed a tutorial on creating an AI and am having issues where they had none

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence

[TheCodeUsed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HwCuN.png)

[NewCodeError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ZKrV.png)

[more errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FN5IH.png)

```
  File "c:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\Elizabeth.py", line 57, in <module>     
    run_Elizabeth()
  
File "c:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\Elizabeth.py", line 35, in run_Elizabeth
    command = take_command()
  
File "c:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\Elizabeth.py", line 32, in take_command
    return command

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment
```

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal try `pip install PyAudio`. If it's already installed, try `pip install PyAudio --upgrade`. You currently don't have version "0.2.11" or newer of pyaudio and apparently that causes issues with the SpeechRecognition library.

Comment: I did as asked and added the () to line 9 but the error does not change

Comment: Make it easier for us both and remove the try/except from the code, so that we can see what the real error is, that is at the moment being "passed". Let me know the error it throws then. Could you show me lines 1-4 too?

Comment: same issue as before minus 32 and adding these
  File "c:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\Elizabeth.py", line 22, in take_command
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 79, in __init__
    self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 112, in get_pyaudio
    if LooseVersion(pyaudio.__version__) < LooseVersion("0.2.11"):
AttributeError: module 'pyaudio' has no attribute '__version__'

Comment: import speech_recognition as sr
import pyttsx3
import datetime
import pyjokes
import pywhatkit
import wikipedia

Comment: in the terminal try `pip install PyAudio`. If it's already installed, try `pip install PyAudio --upgrade`

Comment: PS C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python> pip install pyaudio --upgrade
Requirement already satisfied: pyaudio in f:\python\lib\site-packages (0.2.11)

Comment: here is the youtube video i followed. did everything they did except use a different name
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWvsXxDtEkU

Comment: I'm not sure why it can't find "version", but a possible solution for the sake of getting through this issue, is to go up to `import speech_recognition` and holding Ctrl or CMD on your keyboard, then clicking "speech_recognition". After that you should be in a file called "__init__.py". Head to lines 112 and 113, and delete them and save. After doing this I believe your program should run or at least have a different and unrelated error

Comment: PS C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python> & F:/Python/python.exe c:/Users/Andrew/Desktop/Python/Elizabeth.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\Elizabeth.py", line 22, in take_command
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
  File "F:\Python\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 80, in __init__
    audio = self.pyaudio_module.PyAudio()
AttributeError: module 'pyaudio' has no attribute 'PyAudio'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\Elizabeth.py", line 59, in <module>
    run_Elizabeth()
  File "c:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\Elizabeth.py", line 37, in run_Elizabeth
    command = take_command()
  File "c:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python\Elizabeth.py", line 33, in take_command
    return command
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'command' referenced before assignment
PS C:\Users\Andrew\Desktop\Python>

Comment: Something is very clearly wrong. I would uninstall all of these packages and reinstall them. Maybe install/upgrade to a different version of SpeechRecognition, specifically

Comment: i am thinking something is wrong with my connection with my microphone. i was attempting to start over on the video and am testing things out and before the full amount of code where i can try to talk my microphone is not picking up in the program (visual studio). could that be the problem?

Comment: also, since the run def is not taking the command from takecommand, can we not do this in a way where command would be a global attribute? sorry. learning this all as we go so im not much use atm, just trying to figure things out.

Comment: i moved command=take_command above run and below take and one line of code error is gone. now all that shows is the end run command and now the play command line. does this help?

Comment: I think what you said about it being your microphone could very well be the problem. But I'm not certain

Comment: i think that may be one of the main problems. when i take everything down to return command and run it by itself i get no error code but nothing happens as well.

Comment: i got a different error when ran in a different editor!!! i will edit the above post that you can see it.

Comment: Let me take a look at it when I get off work

Comment: I'm free now, but I don't want to do any investigating unless I get a thumbs up from you saying that you haven't yet fixed it and you still want to. So let me know!

Comment: I have not fixed it yet, i have made things a little better via i was able to correctly get pyaudio per pipwin. i also am using pycharm now and it shows me different errors. like the except being too broad and now there is a problem with the voice area. "Class 'object' does not define '__getitem__', so the '[]' operator cannot be used on its instances"

Comment: had to reset my entire pc so that could be the problem for the voice part but im not sure and idk how to fix it. i joined a discord for python hoping someone there could possibly help as well. but so far not much luck.

Comment: i was able to run the file outside of the editor and she works well. so i am going to close this, thank you so much for helping me and you were a huge help. now i am going to figure out how to add stuff and make her better. again, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

problem was pyaudio installation and program not connecting to microphone. still get the errors in the editor but running the code outside of it works.